# LDAP validation using certificates

Tags: apache, ldap, x509certificate

I've read about this topic in mailing list but I didn't found the solution.
I want validate LDAP users against Apache using the certificates than the user store in LDAP.

I mean, I create and store the X509 certificates in LDAP. Afterwards I send to my clients the certificate and they install those certificates in their browsers.
Now I want validate the users using the certificate instead of the user-name and the password.

I've reading about third party modules (ModXAuthLDAP, mod_authz_ldap) but they are very old and don't work in Apache 2.2.

I’d be interested in comments and some kind of solution to do this authentication process.

Kind regards

Martín Sánchez

Comment: You might be interested in reading about [SASL](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4422).